# How to display an image in full screen on click in the ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, gallery, fullscreen

I need to open an image in full screen upon click in the ImageView, like a gallery with one image! How would I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to follow this tutorial [Zooming a View](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)

Comment: I have added a shema in imageview but the shema is not clear, i would to when I click on this imageview the shema display in full screen I don't know from where start, excuse my poor English :/ her is a screen shot ==> http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/805298Capture.jpg

Comment: michal.z Thanks you thats what i need =D I will try it now

Answer (score 6):

this is a basic example:

the layout `activity_main.xml`

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

`onCreate()` method:

```
private boolean zoomOut =  false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView imageView  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(zoomOut) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NORMAL SIZE!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                zoomOut =false;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FULLSCREEN!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                zoomOut = true;
            }
        }                   
    });
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code to make a zoom in zoom out, hen you click the image.

Comment: @Tony post a question with your problem, I have tested this code by myself and works!.

Comment: have a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230107/image-does-not-display-in-full-screen-when-imageview-is-clicked). Thanks

Comment: This makes a good zoom, but lays out to the left upper corner though.

Answer (score 4):

Jorgesys's answer is good, but to make the image really full screen, a better way would be to make a new dialog/activity with `.NoActionBar.Fullscreen` theme. For example,

```
<style name="FullScreenDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

This new dialog would contain just an image view for your image.

Then you would pass the drawable, or a reference to drawable from your activity to this new one via an intent. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407336/how-to-pass-drawable-between-activities) question for more details on that. (I would suggest passing via some reference, for efficiency concerns).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(this).load(imagePath).into(imageView2);

    }
});
```

xml code..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and also used glide then add below dependecy into app level gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```