# Image does not display in full screen when ImageView is clicked

Tags: android, image, gallery, fullscreen, image-gallery

I wanted to display the full screen of my `bitmap` image(selected from gallery or captured image) when the `imageView` is clicked.

```
 imageView .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if(zoomOut) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NORMAL SIZE!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    zoomOut =false;
                }else{
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FULLSCREEN!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    zoomOut = true;
                }
            }                   
    });
```

**And this is my xml**(Activity B)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/dark_blue"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Enter Claims Information"
            android:id="@+id/textViewClaims"
            android:paddingTop="30sp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <View
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="340sp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Claims Type : "
            android:paddingTop="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textViewClaimsType"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Claims Amount :"
            android:paddingTop="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textViewAmount"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_square"
            android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
            android:hint=" RM "
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.09" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/no_image"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add picture"
            android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Enter Description : "
            android:paddingTop="30sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_square"
            android:layout_weight="0.12"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="80dp"
            android:layout_x="14dp"
            android:layout_y="146dp"
            android:id="@+id/textDescription" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="159dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="save"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Activity B**

Before click

[image]

After click

[image]

Click again to zoom out

[image]

Comment: Ok I see now, first of all you must use a RelativeLayout!, let me work an example (try for now with a relative layout).

Comment: @Elenasys Thanks. I want it only shows image when zoom in.

Comment: @Elenasys I have to change everything in my layout ?

Comment: Anyone has solution ?

Comment: @Tony yes I updated my answer with solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your code with following

```
TextView mTextViewClaims = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewClaims);
TextView mTextViewClaimsType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewClaimsType);
TextView mTextViewAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAmount);
TextView mTextView12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);

EditText mEditTextAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
EditText mTextDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textDescription);

Button mButtonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
Button mButtonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

imageView .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          if(zoomOut) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NORMAL SIZE!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(350 * scale + 0.5f) , (int)(300 * scale + 0.5f)));
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

                mTextViewClaims.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTextViewClaimsType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTextViewAmount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTextView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEditTextAmount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTextDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mButtonAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mButtonSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                

                zoomOut =false;
            }else{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FULLSCREEN!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                float scaleHeigth = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                float scaleWidth = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;         
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)scaleWidth , (int)scaleHeigth));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);                 

                mTextViewClaims.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                mTextViewClaimsType.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                mTextViewAmount.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                mTextView12.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                mEditTextAmount.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                mTextDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                mButtonAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                mButtonSave.setVisibility(View.GONE); 

                zoomOut = true;
            }
        }                   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) The image become larger now but it still doesn't display full screen. I still can see the text in Activity B.

Comment: Means you want to display only image nothing else right..?

Comment: exactly. And when it clicked again, it will zoom out (exactly same with activity B)

Comment: Tony, What if you make invisible the elements?

Comment: @Elenasys Did you mean everything will be invisible except image when zoom in ?

Comment: then you have to set visibility gone of all another view except imageView like .setVisibility(View.GONE); in fullscreen mode and .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); in Normal mode

Comment: @RohitPatil can you work for me , just for the zoom out part

Comment: @Tony answer updated with code, let me know it works or not..!!

Comment: Thanks!! But after I zoom out, the screen looked like the third image I posted...

Comment: After zoom out it should be like first screen right, I changeed the code for same, take it and let me know

Comment: so this is the only way I can use to make it display full screen ? The image can zoom in not in its original size. Btw, the zoom out code works fine