# Pass a XML resource from one activity to another activity using java code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to pass an XML resource from one activity to another activity using Java Code? I don't want to create separate different activities for different buttons.

```
ImageButton imageBttn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

imageBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, info.class));
    }
});
```

Pseudocode to explain what I'm trying to do:

If **BUTTON_1** is clicked
 -*Pass swirl.png to info.class*

If **BUTTON_2** is clicked
 -*Pass golden.png to info.class*

If **BUTTON_3** is clicked
 -*Pass arcade.png*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8407644/4280362

This will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, info.class)
        intent.putExtra("image",R.drawable.ic_search_grey);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

On Mainactvitiy get the int drawable

```
    int res = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", -1);
    if(res > -1) {
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(res, null);
 imgBtn.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

InfoActivity.java

```
public class InfoActivity extends Activity {

  private static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "image";

  public static void launch(Activity activity, @DrawableRes int imageResId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, InfoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, imageResId);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
  }

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    int imageResId = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, -1);
    if (imageResId == -1) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(EXTRA_IMAGE);
      // or set error/default image resource id
    }

    // ... something to do with imageResId
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        InfoActivity.launch(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.swirl);
      }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        InfoActivity.launch(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.golden);
      }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        InfoActivity.launch(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.arcade);
      }
    });
  }
```