# Convert Image from RecyclerView to Bitmap

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I need to send a specific image from my recyclerview that has been clicked to the new activity that will display the image. The question is how do I convert my image to bitmap or something like that so I can send them using intent?
Here's my code:

**RecyclerViewAdapter.kt**

```
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    fun bindItem(items: Item) {
        itemView.name.text = items.name
        itemView.desc.text = items.desc
        Glide.with(itemView.context).load(items.image).into(itemView.image)

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            itemView.context.startActivity(itemView.context.intentFor<DetailsActivity>("image" to bitmap, "name" to items.name, "desc" to items.desc))
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
val intent = intent
    name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
    image = intent.getStringExtra("image")
    desc = intent.getStringExtra("desc")

    nameTextView.text = name
    descTextView.text = desc
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(image)
            .into(imgPhotos)
```

I have already tried all the code that are provided on this site, but they all didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: In your SecondActivity, instead of using `getStringExtra("image")` have you tried with `getParcelableExtra("image")`?

Comment: How should i declare image variable as in the second activity?

Comment: Why dont you send the image url to your activity then load it off the url

Comment: I have my image in my drawable folder

Comment: so send the resource id then

Comment: how can i send the resource id if i'm displaying it as a list in the recyclerview

Comment: how do you get the id to display in the first place? you must have it in your dataset you use in the recyclerview so get it from there

Comment: im displaying them from strings.xml (with the drawable resources) then using for loops to display each of them to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using Glide but it should be like this.

```
 lateinit imageBitmap : Bitmap

 Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load("YOUR_URL").into(object: Target<Bitmap>{
      override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
          imageBitmap = resource
      }
 })
```

You can send Bitmap directly because it is Parcelable

```
intent.putExtra("image",imageBitmap)
```

To getBitmap

```
val bitmap  = intent.extras.getParcelable<Bitmap>("image")
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image to byteArray and pass it through intent. Extract the data through intent on the other side and convert byteArray into bitmap.

Comment: Yes, i have already did that using code that provided all in this site, but that doesn't work!

Comment: Can you tell me the which article?. I just want to see the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407336/how-to-pass-drawable-between-activities